# ASP.NET Identity e mapeamento many to many (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, ddd, fluent-api

Recentemente criei uma Solution com a arquitetura DDD, colocando o ASP.NET `Identity` em uma camada transversal (`CrossCutting`), vi que muitas pessoas utilizam o Identity desta forma e decidi experimentar.

Porém, tive um problema de referência circular.
Para criar uma tabela Associativa (*Many To Many*) eu preciso criar uma `Collection<>` na Entidade da direita, e uma na entidade da esquerda, e criar o `Map` no meu `EntityTypeConfiguration<>`.

Aí que está o problema, como meu projeto `Identity` está separado, e minha Entidade está no projeto `Domain` então não consigo criar uma `Collection<ApplicationUser>` no meu Domain, já que quem tem a referência do `Domain` é meu projeto Identity.

Lembrando também que não consigo usar interface porque o *Migration* não entende Interface.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Olá, Segue link de tutorial de ASP.NET MVC com Identity e Injeção de pendenciaria. http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/

Comment: Na verdade separar um projeto MVC é erradíssimo, até porque o MVC é uma forma de DDD.

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o código com os `namespaces`?

Comment: Pesquisando sobre o assunto, achei este material. Bastante interessante. http://www.jrobertoaraujo.net/2015/06/02/aplicando-crosscutting-ao-aspnet-identity/

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza obrigado pelas menções. Existem dois pensamentos, um é separar em camadas para obter diversos benefícios, manutenção, testes, equipes muito grandes dividindo código, exposição do domínio via serviços, N sistemas, etc... Outro é falar que MVC resolve tudo, bem, se o sistema for uma agenda de contatos ou coisa bem simples ok. Não devemos matar formigas com bolas de canhão.
Antes de decidir sua arquitetura analise sua necessidade. Sobre MVC ser uma forma de DDD e ou o MVC ser o suficiente para desenvolver um sistema corporativo complexo, desculpe, isso não existe.

Comment: @EduardoPires Nas novas versões do Sharepoint, a arquitetura é inteira em ASP.NET MVC. O Umbraco, CMS também é em ASP.NET MVC. Uma separação de camadas razoável utiliza IoC, Unity e DI. Outra coisa é propor uma separação utilizando DDD e as pessoas realmente acharem que é o melhor padrão quando não é. A meu ver, é um anti-padrão.

Answer (score 6):

> Antes de mais nada, gostaria de dizer que precisei estudar essa solução durante as semanas de intervalo em que a pergunta foi feita e agora e um bom tempo após, porque eu realmente não tinha conhecimento de como fazer, e mesmo depois que escrevi a primeira versão da resposta muitas coisas estavam incorretas e imprecisas. Insisto tanto nela para exemplificar até onde um anti-padrão pode ir, em nome das tão faladas boas práticas arquiteturais em sistemas ASP.NET.
>
> A primeira solução não é minha. Ela foi elaborada brilhantemente pelo [José Roberto Araújo](http://www.jrobertoaraujo.net/about/) em [link](http://www.jrobertoaraujo.net/2015/06/02/aplicando-crosscutting-ao-aspnet-identity/) passado pelo [Gustavo H. Pereira Silva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/27881/gustavo-h-pereira-silva). Sem isso, essa resposta não seria possível.
>
> [O repositório original da solução era este](https://github.com/jr-araujo/WebAppIdentityDemo), mas o autor o apagou. [Fiz um *fork* para estudar](https://github.com/cigano/WebAppIdentityDemo) (este ainda existe), fiz algumas modificações, atualizei os pacotes e fiz testes pra compreender as coisas que, até pelo menos o mês passado, pra mim eram mágicas e que muito me surpreenderam. Possivelmente vou atualizar essa resposta algumas vezes porque muita coisa não está bem documentada e o aprendizado acabou sendo por empirismo.

## Uma demonstração de separação usando *Cross-Cutting*, IoC e DI do ASP.NET Identity do restante da Aplicação MVC (e porque ela não funciona)

A rigor, este projeto não está exatamente e totalmente desacoplado da *Class Library* da Infraestrutura. Isto pode ser notado ao abrir uma das *Views* que utiliza o ASP.NET Identity:

### `~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml`

```
@model WebAppSoC.Infrastructure.Crosscutting.Security.Model.Account.LoginViewModel

...
```

O correto aqui seria haver uma interface para a *View*, e não a exposição do *ViewModel* em si, mas está ok para nosso exemplo.

### [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator), [Unity Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507440(v=pandp.30).aspx) e [Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.web.infrastructure/)

A mágica toda começa com esses três componentes. O WebActivator é a porta de entrada para a injeção de dependência em si, permitindo que o desenvolvedor configure quantas classes de `Startup` preferir para registrar os componentes externos que poderão ser usados na injeção de dependência.

O Unity MVC é o componente que realiza a injeção de dependência de fato na aplicação. Na época que escrevi a primeira versão da resposta, achei que componentes MVC como *Controllers*, *Models*, e até *Views* eram injetados magicamente da *Class Library* para a aplicação ASP.NET MVC. Na verdade, ao registrar o *Container* do Unity MVC na aplicação, a aplicação não mapeia sozinha os *Controllers* injetados para as respectivas rotas da configuração do projeto original. Observe que o arquivo que ativa o Unity MVC não diz qualquer informação a respeito de rotas:

#### WebAppIdentityDemo/Jra.Infrastructure/CrossCutting/Dependency/Startup/UnityMvcActivator.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Jra.Infrastructure.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Jra.Infrastructure.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace Jra.Infrastructure.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui que entra o Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure: não há muita informação sobre ele, mas a descrição do pacote no NuGet diz:

> This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically register HTTP modules at run time.

E aqui está o segredo: é este pacote que faz suas *Class Libraries* serem registradas em aplicações ASP.NET MVC. O padrão implementado é semelhante ao [Common Service Locator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/), mas sem criar dependência com este último.

Note que não há registro adicional de rotas. O arquivo de rotas prova isso:

### `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`

```
namespace WebAppIdentityDemo
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

O arquivo `Global.asax.cs` também:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebAppIdentityDemo
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

O arquivo `packages.config` do projeto Web atesta a total independência do projeto Web do ASP.NET Identity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

O desenvolvedor mais atento ira notar que o arquivo `packages.config` da solução principal não possui as seguintes entradas:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Isto porque toda classe que herda `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` passa a ser percebida pelo controlador de rota. Este é o segredo de pacotes como, por exemplo, o [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/) ([packages.config aqui](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/blob/master/RazorGenerator.Mvc/packages.config)). O RazorGenerator permite ao desenvolvedor escrever *Class Libraries* que contenham *Controllers* e *Views* e possam ser incorporadas a outras aplicações ASP.NET MVC da mesma forma.

No todo, há apenas duas menções à *Class Library* de Infraestrutura no projeto Web:

- A referência à *Class Library*;
- A ativação do *Container* em `Startup.cs` do diretório raiz.

Esta ativação é feita da seguinte forma:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using WebAppSoC.Infrastructure.Crosscutting.Security.Startup;

[assembly: OwinStartup("StartupConfiguration", typeof(WebAppIdentityDemo.Startup))]
namespace WebAppIdentityDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            new IdentityStartup().Configuration(app);
        }
    }
}
```

## Por que mostrei tudo isso

A ideia é mostrar que é possível a separação, mas não 100% independente. Ainda há um grau de acoplamento que não é possível de ser eliminado.

## Sobre a pergunta

A separação é simplesmente ilógica. [O ASP.NET Identity é fortemente acoplado ao Entity Framework no *template* padrão](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) (que usa o pacote [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/)). É feito assim porque a ideia é que o domínio (*Models* da aplicação) possa ser customizado de modo a incorporar mais informações em, por exemplo, a estrutura de usuários, *roles*, *claims*, e assim por diante.

Ainda, se a separação é imprescindível, o desenvolvedor deve incorporar, em uma mesma camada, Entity Framework e ASP.NET Identity, ou implementar seu próprio [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) e [RoleStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/RoleStore.cs), componentes estes necessários para o funcionamento do ASP.NET Identity sem depender do Entity Framework, o que é uma ideia bastante inútil sem um bom motivo para isso.

## Conclusão

Não use *Cross-Cutting*. Neste escopo de aplicação, ele não tem utilidade. Só atrapalha seu trabalho e não propicia qualquer ganho para a sua aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você está trabalhando com dois contextos do EF no mesmo banco de dados. Um contexto apenas para o `Identity` e outro para o resto da aplicação.

Eu também utilizo esta abordagem, uma vez que a função do `Identity` é cuidar da Autenticação e Autorização dos usuários. Isolo o contexto do `Identity` e restrinjo a utilização dele apenas para isso.

Logo se você precisa relacionar o usuário com outra entidade e esta entidade não tem relação com Autenticação ou Autorização dos usuários. Você deve criar uma classe que represente o seu usuário no seu projeto `Domain` sem nenhuma referência para o `Identity`. E mapear esta tabela dentro do contexto que trata toda a aplicação. E neste contexto você pode fazer o relacionamento dos usuários com a outra entidade.

Ou seja, você terá dois objetos diferentes (um no projeto `Domain` e outro no projeto `Identity`) que representam a mesma tabela no banco de dados. Se houver alteração nesta tabela, você precisará alterar os dois objetos. Será preciso mais cuidado com a manutenção deste projeto, mas você resolve o problema da dependência do `Identity`.

Comment: Isto é uma solução perigosa, mas admito que funciona. Não é recomendado mapear duas estruturas em separado apenas para poder contar com uma separação em camadas, cuja utilidade é discutível.

Comment: Por quê devemos quebrar os contextos por interesses, isolar o contexto do Identity proporciona escalar o mesmo mecanismo para diferentes sistemas que usam o mesmo meio de acesso.
Quebrar contextos do EF é uma estratégia recomendada amplamente. Citando Eduardo Pires em um comentário do artigo: http://eduardopires.net.br/2015/02/customizando-nomes-tabelas-campos-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Eduardo Pires é a mesma pessoa que faz um tutorial de separação por camadas e as pessoas que seguem vem pra cá tirar dúvida. Desculpe, não é argumento.

Comment: Eu estudo os tutoriais e venho aqui ajudar a tirar dúvidas. Mas este já é outro assunto. A separação do código em camadas tem sua utilidade. Principalmente quando pensamos não apenas na construção de um sistema, mas também na manutenção do mesmo.

Comment: Imagine uma aplicação feita sem nenhuma separação de camadas, que foi criada utilizando EF para acesso a dados e todos os controllers da aplicação instanciam diretamente o contexto. Se um dia o EF for descontinuado e surgir um ORM melhor, a programador que tiver que evoluir este sistema terá muito mais trabalho para adaptar esse sistema ao novo ORM. Se tivesse feito uma separação de camadas por responsabilidade e utilizado injeção de dependência, esse trabalho seria extremamente focado em criar a nova camada acesso a dados. Teria trabalho também, mas muito mais organizado, focado e mensurável.

Comment: Desculpe novamente. Vou discordar de você. A separação do código **em nada ajuda** a manter uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC. Isto é uma prática antiga, de arquiteturas 3 camadas, em que era necessário separar um domínio da aplicação e fazer ele ser visível pelas demais. O EF é um repositório completo: se você precisar retirá-lo, pode fazer em um comando apenas e instalar outro de sua preferência que a solução alternativa se acopla perfeitamente à aplicação. É por isso que podemos afirmar que o MVC implementa o DDD.

Comment: Ok. E todas as referências ao EF que você adicionou nos seus Controllers? Vai mudar uma por uma na mão?

Comment: Se eu não soubesse refatorar código, sim. Mas posso extrair uma interface de `DbContext` e implementar um repositório baseado em, por exemplo, Dapper. Que tal?

Comment: Já melhorou. Agora se você precisar utilizar esse repositório que utiliza a interface que você extraiu do DbContext em outros projetos. Como faria? Ctrl+C + Ctrl+V?

Comment: Quais outros projetos? Qual a função deles? São módulos? São sistemas que acessam o primeiro sistema? Sua ideia é copiar-e-colar uma DLL em um outro sistema ou consumir as informações do sistema em outro?

Comment: Estamos falando de repositório. Preciso usar a mesma abstração feita no DbContext em outro projeto para que meus Controllers não dependam do EF.

Comment: Não faz sentido isso que você falou. Se você quer usar a abstração de um projeto em outro, servir a base de dados inteira já é errado. Há vários conceitos e vícios que são usados de arquiteturas em 3 camadas, e que as pessoas simplesmente implementam sem questionar. O correto seria a aplicação MVC servir os dados para a outra aplicação de outra forma, seja por uma DLL fechada, seja por uma interface REST API, e assim por diante.

Comment: Estou falando apenas das interfaces, não das classes que a implementam.

Comment: Cara, enquanto o pensamento continuar engessado não há como sair do lugar. O MVC foi feito pra eliminar prolixidade e retrabalho, que é justamente o que uma proposta "bem-intencionada" de separação em camadas tenta trazer novamente. Os tutoriais que vi têm 3 horas de duração. Com este tempo é possível modelar, gerar e testar vários aspectos de um sistema MVC sem se preocupar tanto com interfaces e "design responsável". Essa pergunta mesmo é gerada por um vício de prática. Se houvesse entendimento dos novos conceitos, ela possivelmente nem existiria.

Comment: Realmente, desenvolver uma aplicação utilizando um único projeto é bem mais rápido e funciona muito bem para pequenos projetos e de baixa complexidade. Quando se trabalha com aplicações maiores e mais complexas, se não pensarmos em um "design responsável" podemos ter grandes dores de cabeça no futuro. Como já vi acontecer em algumas das empresas em que trabalhei.